# PowerAutomate - Condition for exactly 30 days ago

Tags: power-automate

My workflow gets items from a sharepoint list and reoccurs every day. Based on the 'ValidUntil' data field which is of type `DateTime`, I want the workflow condition result to be true if the date is exactly 30 days in the future, so it can send an email.

[image]

Expression used:
`addDays(utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd'),30)`

The problem I am facing, is that the expression is true only if the time matches up exactly with the 'ValidUntil' value. These values are differing, I'm trying to make it ignore the time and only look at the amount of days (30). From my research, it's been said that including the date format `('yyyy-MM-dd')` will ignore the time values but this is not the case from testing the workflow.

I have also tried using a 'Compose' step by formatting the 'ValidUntil' values to the same date format under an 'Apply to each' step named 'Compose_Valid_Until'

`formatDateTime(items('Apply_to_each')?['ValidUntil'], 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Based on the workflow history, I can see the date input is correct but the workflow is activated every time for very differing dates.

`outputs('Compose_Valid_Until')` is equal to `addDays(utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd'),30)`

I think that using outputs is getting **all** values and if **any** of them match, send an email for every item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the approach is valid, but the Compose step is not the correct tool to use here.

Why not declare a string variable beforehand and set its value to the result of the `formatDateTime()` expression? That way you are comparing string to string, while the `outputs()` function is giving you an object I guess.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked. When adding the days, I had to use another variable where I formatted the future date, then compare string variable to another string variable. 

formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), 30), 'yyyy-MM-dd')